# Ошибка в http запросе

Tags: xml, http, javascript

Ошибка

```
Возникло исключение в строке 4, столбце 9 в ms-appx://2460180a-5292-4099-a890-a962bda994c0/js/script_program.js
0x800a01ad - Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: Невозможно создание объекта сервером программирования объектов
Возникло исключение в строке 7, столбце 13 в ms-appx://2460180a-5292-4099-a890-a962bda994c0/js/script_program.js
0x800a01ad - Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: Невозможно создание объекта сервером программирования объектов
```

Код

```
function getXmlHttp() {

     var xmlhttp;
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }
    function get_channel(name_channel,country) {
        if (name_channel == '1') {
            var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://iamilya.ru/images/ILItv/RU/1_RU.html', false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: говорит, что не может создать объект. проверьте настройки безопасности.

Comment: Я не могу их найти